# Get any fragment instance using Navigation component

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-navigation

Inorder to get instance of fragment previously we used `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(yourTag)` however with new `Navigation component` I don't seem to find a way to set fragment tag or to get instance of any fragment not just currently visible fragment.

Exactly like this old approach but of course it can not be used with navigation component

Set Tag

```
MyFragment fragment  = new MyFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.place_holder,fragment,"myFragmentTag");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

get Fragment instance

```
fragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myFragmentTag");
if(fragment != null){
    // ok, we got the fragment instance, but should we manipulate its view?
}
```

As seen in above code, is there a way to get instance of Fragment using navigation component?

Comment: Why you want to get a fragment instance? Do you need to manipulate its view while it's not the top fragment? or you just want to send it some data from the current destination?

Comment: I want to be able to programmatically change viewpager screen based on button clicks, For that i will need reference of mainFragment where i initialized viewPager. If i have access to the instance ViewPager fragment, I can get viewPager and then i will be able to change screens programmatically using `fragmentInstance.viewPager.setCurrentItem(pageNumber)` in child fragments. @Zain